# Replacing bulb - Poisson process

Tags: markov-process, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

A bulb at the entrance of a building has a lifetime of exponential expectancy $100$ days. When burned, the concierge immediately replaced with a new one. In addition, an employee who takes care of the daily maintenance rempalce the bulb with a new one as a precaution according to a Poisson process with intensity $0.02$ per day. Determine : **(a)** the rate of replacement of the bulb? **(b)** the probability that the next bulb is replaced by the concierge

I succeed to do **(a)** and I obtain $0,01 + 0,02 = 0,03$. However, I blocked on (b) since a good while.

I'm not very aged ($13$ years old) and often I need a little help to solve a problem. This question seems difficult to do and I do not know how to approach it. Does anyone could provide a detailed and complete answer to this question (part **(b)**)?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** If, as you surmise, on any given day, the concierge replaces the bulb at rate $0.01$, and the maintenance employee replaces the bulb at rate $0.02$, how many times more likely is the maintenance employee to replace the bulb than the concierge?

And since *one* of them must eventually replace any given bulb, what is the probability that it is the concierge?